# Laravel best way to make an AJAX GET request with parameters

Tags: ajax, laravel, get, request

Route:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', "UserController@get")->name('user');//Get all users is not allowed.
```

Form:

```
<form>
<select id="selected_user">
<option value="1">Bob</option>
<option value="2">Alice</option>
</select>
<button id="get_user">Query</button>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ route('user')}}"+id,
  type: "GET",
  data: null,
  dataType: 'json':
}).done(function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

**What you get:** `development.ERROR: Missing required parameters for [Route: user] [URI: user/{id}] [Missing parameters: id].`

Yeah but I still don't know which user I will select, so I can't put a parameter there...

Workaround 1:

```
POST Request (But I am not POST ing anything?)
```

Workaround 2 in AJAX:

```
let id = getHTMLId();
url: {{ URL::to('/'); }}+"/user/"+id;//I will have to update all AJAX requests if there is a change to URL so it is now: users/get/{id}
```

Workaround 3 (I don't know if this is even possible):

```
Route::get('/user/{id?}', "UserController@get")->name('user');//Optional parameters, but the application should not be allowing a request to /users/ alone.
```

Expected method from Laravel

**URL::routeWithoutParams('user');//Where user is the named route**

Is there a proper way to do a simple GET request?

I haven't found any information and all examples seem to read entire data like users/getall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass parameters with route as you are doing.

```
url:"{{ route('user')}}"+id, //This is wrong way
```

Correct way is:

```
var url = "{{route('user', ':id')}}";
url = url.replace(':id', id);
```

use above `url` variable with ajax call.

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
let tmpUrl = "{{ route('user', 0)}}";
tmpUrl = tmpUrl.substr(0, tmpUrl.length - 1) + id;
```

or

```
let tmpUrl = "{{ route('user', '---')}}";
tmpUrl = tmpUrl.replace('---', id);
```